# Prime numbers- Dilemma

Tags: java, loops, netbeans

I am trying to check whether the given number is prime or not. By first using trial division method. But the program is behaving weirdly. Here's what I used.

```
int no;
no = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());

for (int i = 2; i < no; i = i + 1) {
   if(no % i == 0) {
      jTextArea1.setText("No. is not prime");
   }
   else {
      jTextArea1.setText("No is prime");
   }
}
```

The program always displays the output as "No is prime". 
I know its quite a trivial problem but help would be appreciated.

P.S. I am using Netbeans.

Comment: for all `i>2`, `i%(i-1) = 1`. So on the last iteration of your loop, the textarea is always set to `"No is prime"`

Comment: @sam007 there is a flaw in your logic. check it dude. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you are resetting the text on each iteration.  Even after you have found a divisor for `no` and set the text to indicate that it is not prime, you continue to check additional numbers, which will not divide into your number evenly.

What you want to be doing instead, is checking for 'primeness' each time through your loop, but only set the text once:

```
    boolean prime = true;
    for (int i = 2; i < no; i = i + 1) {
        if (no % i == 0) {
            jTextArea1.setText("No. is not prime");
            prime = false;
            break;  // once we have found a divisor, we can stop looking
        }
    }
    if (prime) {
        jTextArea1.setText("No is prime")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you find a divisor, you still keep running the loop.

There are several ways to solve this.  The simplest is that when you find a divisor, you quit the loop:

```
for (int i=2;i<no;i=i+1 ){
    if(no%i==0) {
        jTextArea1.setText("No. is not prime"); 
        break;
    }
    else {
        jTextArea1.setText("No is prime");
    }
}
```

`break` stops the loop immediately.

You should also realize that if `i` *is* a divisor, you will be calling the same `setText` over and over, which really shouldn't be necessary.  You could instead do this once, before the loop:

```
jTextArea1.setText("No is prime");
for (int i=2; i<no; i=i+1) {
    if(no%i==0) {
        jTextArea1.setText("No. is not prime"); 
        break;
    }
}
```

What this does is set the text to `"No is prime"`; then if it finds a divisor, it changes it to `"No. is not prime"` and then exits the loop because it's not necessary to keep going.  (Note that doing it this way means it will work if `no` is 2.  In your original code, the loop would not run at all and the effect is that the text area would never be set to anything.)  In practice, I'd use a `boolean` as azurefrog recommended, so that the text area isn't set twice (for a large number, setting it to say `"No is prime"` and then changing it a half second later could be disconcerting to a user).